# How to deal with multiple versions of OpenSSL linked to my app?

Tags: linux, openssl

My application is linked with OpenSSL 1.0.1. I need to link with a 3rd party library that's linked with its own version of OpenSSL (0.9.8).

Unfortunately resulting application crashes somewhere inside libcrypto. I'm pretty sure that's due to conflicting versions of OpenSSL.

How to deal with it on Linux? I would like to avoid moving all the logic to interact with 3rd party library into another app and use any form of IPC.

Comment: Does it crash immediately? Or does it take awhile before it crashes? Do you have a stack trace?

Comment: I have a similar problem. In my case, the 3rd party lib is distributed as a static library and it even comes with a script to remove the OpenSSL objects from the `.a` file but it does not seem to be a good idea to replace a 0.9.8 version of OpenSSL with anything else, see http://abi-laboratory.pro/tracker/timeline/openssl/ .